# How to upload memory file to amazon S3?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload a file from my memoryStream to amazon S3 server.

Here is the code:

```
public static bool memUploadFile(AmazonS3 client, MemoryStream memFile, string toPath)
{

    try
    {
        Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility tranUtility = new Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility(client);
        tranUtility.Upload(filePath, toPath.Replace("\\", "/"));

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Then the error says,

"the best overload method match for 'Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility.Uplaod(string,string)' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: You have not specified what filePath points to. Also, "a file from my memorystream" doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 9):

Look at the [Upload Method (stream, bucketName, key)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_Transfer_TransferUtility_Upload_1.htm)

```
public static bool memUploadFile(AmazonS3 client, MemoryStream memFile, string toPath)
{
    try
    {
        using(Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility tranUtility =
                      new Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility(client))
        {
            tranUtility.Upload(memFile, toPath.Replace("\\", "/"), <The key under which the Amazon S3 object is stored.>);

            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Hamlet is right. This is an example TransferUtilityUploadRequest

```
    [Test]
    public void UploadMemoryFile()
    {
        var config = CloudConfigStorage.GetAdminConfig();

        string bucketName = config.BucketName;
        string clientAccessKey = config.ClientAccessKey;
        string clientSecretKey = config.ClientSecretKey;

        string path = Path.GetFullPath(@"dummy.txt");
        File.WriteAllText(path, DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

        using (var client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(clientAccessKey, clientSecretKey))
        using (var transferUtility = new TransferUtility(client))
        {

            var request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Key = "memory.txt",
                InputStream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path))
            };

            transferUtility.Upload(request);
        }
    }
```